# How can I get the start and end dates for each week?

Tags: python

```
week = datetime.date(2022,4,10).isocalendar()[1]
```

After finding the week, how can I get the start and end date of the week?

Comment: What did you try and why didn't it work? [Ask]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Python 3.6 version of rshepp's answer:

```
from datetime import datetime, date

year, week, day = date(2022, 4, 10).isocalendar()

date_first = datetime.strptime(f'{year}{week}0', '%Y%U%w')
date_last = datetime.strptime(f'{year}{week}6', '%Y%U%w')

print(date_first, date_last, sep='\n')
```

Output, Sunday-Saturday

```
2022-04-03 00:00:00
2022-04-09 00:00:00
```

---

```
date_first = datetime.strptime(f'{year}{week}1', '%Y%U%w')
date_last = datetime.strptime(f'{year}{week+1}0', '%Y%U%w')
print(date_first, date_last, sep='\n')
```

Output, Monday-Sunday

```
2022-04-04 00:00:00
2022-04-10 00:00:00
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `date.fromisocalendar`, such as:

```py
import datetime

year, week, day = datetime.date(2022, 4, 10).isocalendar()

date_first = datetime.date.fromisocalendar(year, week, 1)
date_last = datetime.date.fromisocalendar(year, week, 7)

print(date_first)
print(date_last)
```

Comment: My python version is 3.6, so it doesn't work. Is there any other way?

Comment: @han I added a 3.6 version~

Answer (score 0):

I really appreciate @BeRT2me for posting the solution. However, the solution doesn't exactly match the `fromisocalendar` function, it seems that the `week` starts from 0 while `fromisocalendar`'s starts from 1. In addition, the solution assumes that Jan 1st is Monday, so for a year that the Jan 1st is not Monday, such as 2023, it shows
`date_first = 2023-01-02 00:00:00`
`date_last = 2023-01-01 00:00:00`

I don't really have a more elegant workaround, and I just copy the `fromisocalendar` function source code into a new file and import that.

```
MINYEAR = 1
MAXYEAR = 9999
_MAXORDINAL = 3652059  # date.max.toordinal()

def _days_before_year(year):
    "year -> number of days before January 1st of year."
    y = year - 1
    return y*365 + y//4 - y//100 + y//400

_DAYS_IN_MONTH = [-1, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31]
_DAYS_BEFORE_MONTH = [-1]  # -1 is a placeholder for indexing purposes.
dbm = 0
for dim in _DAYS_IN_MONTH[1:]:
    _DAYS_BEFORE_MONTH.append(dbm)
    dbm += dim
del dbm, dim

def _is_leap(year):
    "year -> 1 if leap year, else 0."
    return year % 4 == 0 and (year % 100 != 0 or year % 400 == 0)

def _days_in_month(year, month):
    "year, month -> number of days in that month in that year."
    assert 1 <= month <= 12, month
    if month == 2 and _is_leap(year):
        return 29
    return _DAYS_IN_MONTH[month]

def _days_before_month(year, month):
    "year, month -> number of days in year preceding first day of month."
    assert 1 <= month <= 12, 'month must be in 1..12'
    return _DAYS_BEFORE_MONTH[month] + (month > 2 and _is_leap(year))

def _ymd2ord(year, month, day):
    "year, month, day -> ordinal, considering 01-Jan-0001 as day 1."
    assert 1 <= month <= 12, 'month must be in 1..12'
    dim = _days_in_month(year, month)
    assert 1 <= day <= dim, ('day must be in 1..%d' % dim)
    return (_days_before_year(year) +
            _days_before_month(year, month) +
            day)

def _isoweek1monday(year):
    # Helper to calculate the day number of the Monday starting week 1
    # XXX This could be done more efficiently
    THURSDAY = 3
    firstday = _ymd2ord(year, 1, 1)
    firstweekday = (firstday + 6) % 7  # See weekday() above
    week1monday = firstday - firstweekday
    if firstweekday > THURSDAY:
        week1monday += 7
    return week1monday

_DI400Y = _days_before_year(401)    # number of days in 400 years
_DI100Y = _days_before_year(101)    #    "    "   "   " 100   "
_DI4Y   = _days_before_year(5)      #    "    "   "   "   4   "

def _ord2ymd(n):
    "ordinal -> (year, month, day), considering 01-Jan-0001 as day 1."
    n -= 1
    n400, n = divmod(n, _DI400Y)
    year = n400 * 400 + 1   # ..., -399, 1, 401, ...

    n100, n = divmod(n, _DI100Y)
    n4, n = divmod(n, _DI4Y)

    n1, n = divmod(n, 365)

    year += n100 * 100 + n4 * 4 + n1
    if n1 == 4 or n100 == 4:
        assert n == 0
        return year-1, 12, 31

    leapyear = n1 == 3 and (n4 != 24 or n100 == 3)
    assert leapyear == _is_leap(year)
    month = (n + 50) >> 5
    preceding = _DAYS_BEFORE_MONTH[month] + (month > 2 and leapyear)
    if preceding > n:  # estimate is too large
        month -= 1
        preceding -= _DAYS_IN_MONTH[month] + (month == 2 and leapyear)
    n -= preceding
    assert 0 <= n < _days_in_month(year, month)

    return year, month, n+1


# tuple[int, int, int] -> tuple[int, int, int] version of date.fromisocalendar
def _isoweek_to_gregorian(year, week, day):
    # Year is bounded this way because 9999-12-31 is (9999, 52, 5)
    if not MINYEAR <= year <= MAXYEAR:
        raise ValueError(f"Year is out of range: {year}")

    if not 0 < week < 53:
        out_of_range = True

        if week == 53:
            # ISO years have 53 weeks in them on years starting with a
            # Thursday and leap years starting on a Wednesday
            first_weekday = _ymd2ord(year, 1, 1) % 7
            if (first_weekday == 4 or (first_weekday == 3 and
                                    _is_leap(year))):
                out_of_range = False

        if out_of_range:
            raise ValueError(f"Invalid week: {week}")

    if not 0 < day < 8:
        raise ValueError(f"Invalid weekday: {day} (range is [1, 7])")

    # Now compute the offset from (Y, 1, 1) in days:
    day_offset = (week - 1) * 7 + (day - 1)

    # Calculate the ordinal day for monday, week 1
    day_1 = _isoweek1monday(year)
    ord_day = day_1 + day_offset

    return _ord2ymd(ord_day)

def fromisocalendar(year, week, day):
        """Construct a date from the ISO year, week number and weekday.

        This is the inverse of the date.isocalendar() function"""
        return _isoweek_to_gregorian(year, week, day)
```

(I am posting here because I don't have 50 reputation to add a comment)